# Is it possible to pass the check box values by default

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I have 3 check boxes in my app...i have 5 attributes for each table.Attributes are **reminderDaysId,date,typeId,isSelected,isDelete**...
By default i need to pass 3 check box value to database...

If check box 1 is clicked i need to pass **reminderDaysId,date,typeId,isDelete with isselected is 1...**

Here other two check boxes are not clicked..Even though i need to pass **reminderDaysId,date,typeId,isDelete with isselected is 0...**

For clicked check box i need to pass isselected is 1...For unclicked check box isSelected is 0....

Is it possible to pass the values to database ...

Comment: check the checkbox is checked or not. if one is checked the chech the other two.

Comment: I dont know how to check that..Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Make an object for each checkbox

```
CheckBox ch1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
```

then

```
if(ch1.isChecked())
{
//do what you want
}
```

Comment: Thank u for your reply..i found the solution